# What is the best way to clone an object into a Map without looping?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I was trying to convert an object which is used for a map purpose, into a proper Map object. I can iterate over the result of `Object.keys()` and do like

```
var myData = {"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3},    
     myMap = Object.keys(myData).reduce((m,k) => m.set(k,myData[k]) ,new Map());
```

which does the job. However i gave a try to `Object.assign()` like

```
var myData = {"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3},
     myMap = Object.assign(new Map(),myData);
```

which yields a Map with proper key / value pairs yet the `size` property always show 0. What's going on here and what would be another nice way to make this conversion that i can not think of..? I am open to any ideas from ES6 and beyond.

Comment: When you use `Object.assign`, you're just creating new properties on the `Map` object, not actually storing anything in the map.

Comment: @Bergi He is asking why the size property always zero even the map got created successfully. I think the linked question won't answer this.

Comment: @Bergi oops. Sorry I forgot to read your comment fully.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: The dupe answers the title question, and the "and …" part of the question in the post body. One should only ask one question per post :-) So if "*What is going on here?*" is not sufficiently answered by my comment, the OP best should ask a new question.

Comment: @Bergi i am very confused.. how come an iterable object can have several properties and at the same time have a length property with value "zero"

Comment: @Redu A map doesn't iterate its properties, it iterates the values stored inside it. It's like you're setting arbitrary properties on an array, only indices are getting iterated (but in contrast to an Array, the keys and values of a Map are not available as properties).